# PHP rename with date stamp

Tags: php, date, rename

we want to make a script that renames the file name with a date stamp, we're new to PHP so this is what we have now.

```
<?php rename("test.txt", "tes3.txt"); ?>
```

we tried some with things like this below but we don't get it to work.

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

I hope you guys have a answer how we can do this.
Thanks

Comment: `rename("test.txt", $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP'));` where is the problem?!

Comment: So does it not echo the date? Seems like it would. So just save the date in a variable by replacing `echo` with `$filename = ` and replacing `"\n"` with `".txt"`

Comment: Thanks for ur reactions used the answer from CommuSoft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is use the textual output (string) produced by `$date->format(...)` and inject the answer in the rename call.

```
$date = new DateTime();
rename("test.txt", "test" . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . ".txt");
```

But it is advisable to not use any spaces in filenames, especially if you want the files to be accessible through a server/website/...

Comment: Thanks for your help, its working now. I removed the spaces aswel.